# getting different counts from two different tables?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm having trouble with a query I'm trying to write in oracle.

Basically I want to get the count of two tables that have the same provider list. I can run the query individually but not sure how to do it in one shot.

Here's a example:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name)
FROM   table1
group by name
```

This gives me a list of names and a count beside them.  If I run the same command but on table2(changing the from statement), it works fine.  What I want to do is have a query that takes count from table1 and substracts it from count from table2.

How can I do it? I have tried to do nested selects and so on but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: not sure how to post the table structure.  Basically for each name, I want to get the counts for two different tables(then substract them) so for example: 
name    countTable1  countTable2  difference
john     5        8         3
bob      2        4         2

Comment: Use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/728c8/10/0) to share schema and queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option assuming that the `name` values in both tables are identical would be

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.cnt - t1.cnt diff
  FROM( SELECT name, COUNT(name) cnt 
          FROM table1
         group by name ) t1,
      ( SELECT name, COUNT(name) cnt 
          FROM table2
         group by name ) t2
 WHERE t1.name = t2.name
```

If you want to handle the case where one table has a `name` that the other doesn't but you don't know which table has the extra name (and assuming that you want to say that the other table has a `cnt` of 0 for that `name`)

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) name, 
       nvl(t1.cnt, 0 ) t1_cnt,
       nvl(t2.cnt, 0 ) t2_cnt,
       nvl(t2.cnt,0) - nvl(t1.cnt,0) diff
  FROM( SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS cnt
          FROM table1
         group by table1.name ) t1
      full outer join
      ( SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS cnt
          FROM table2
         group by table2.name ) t2
      on( t1.name = t2.name )
```

which you can see in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56a22/5)

Comment: Hi Justin. Thank you. yes name values are the same for both tables. I'm trying to apply to my query but I'm getting a error when referring to cnt..how can I refer to the count?

Comment: @user1735075 the aliases were missing from the subqueries, it should work now

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/728c8/10/0 this also shows that data must exist in both tables to be subtracted, any way to edit this so that records can exist in one and not the other?

Comment: @Jason Sperske - Updated my answer if we want to consider the potential for names to exist in one table but not another.

Comment: Thanks it all worked! I think I can apply this logic to many other queries. Learned alot, Thanks Justin!